# Getting M2M field data in template Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to get m2m data in my template through the views but failing to do so. The thing is that I'm able to show the data of m2m field looping it from template itself but it does slow down the website.

My Team apps Model looks like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team_country = CountryField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)          
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teams')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_teams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in my tournament app I'm trying to get "members" of the team.

My Tournamet Views look like this:

```
def tournament_page(request, slug):
    page = 'tournament_page'
    user = request.user
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(slug=slug)
    players = tournament.participants.select_related('user')
    all_players = Profile.objects.select_related('user')
    side_tourneys_ongoing = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Ongoing')[:10]
    side_tourneys_upcoming = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Upcoming')[:10]
    side_tourneys_completed = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Completed')[:10]
    teams = Team.objects.select_related('created_by')
        
         
    
context = {
    'page': page,
    'tournament': tournament, 
    'side_tourneys_ongoing': side_tourneys_ongoing,
    'side_tourneys_upcoming': side_tourneys_upcoming,
    'side_tourneys_completed': side_tourneys_completed, 
    'teams': teams, 
    'players':players, 
    'all_players':all_players
}
```

Now I'm able to show the teams with their members in the template using for loop inside the template itself as:

Html template

```
<div class="grid-x">
    {% for team in teams %}
    {% for player in players %}
    {% if team.id == player.active_team_id and team.game == tournament.game %}
    <div class="wf-card event-team">
        <div> {{team.title}} </div>
        <div class="event-team-players">            
            {% for member in team.members.all %}            
                {{ member.username }}    
            {% endfor %}                                  
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}           
</div>
```

What I want is to use this piece of code

```
{% for member in team.members.all %}            
   {{ member.username }}    
{% endfor %}
```

in my views since it causes the website to slow down and idk why.

What I tried in my views is:

```
all_teams = Team.objects.all()

members = all_teams.members.all()
```

and

**members = Team.objects.all().prefetch_related('members')**

First one throws an error:

*'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'members'*

Second one shows lots of blank records

Tried almost everything with search but none of them helped except using the code that I provided directly in the template itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't access to members of ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980422/cant-access-to-members-of-manytomanyfield)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1841931

Comment: I'm having issue to follow up those answers, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you please write your solution? And I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comments below. You should be able to do this more simply by prefetching team members.

views.py

```
def tournament_page(request, slug):
    page = 'tournament_page'
    user = request.user
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(slug=slug)
    all_players = Profile.objects.select_related('user')
    side_tourneys_ongoing = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Ongoing')[:10]
    side_tourneys_upcoming = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Upcoming')[:10]
    side_tourneys_completed = Tournament.objects.filter(state='Completed')[:10]
    teams = Team.objects.select_related('created_by').prefetch_related('members')
```

template.html

```
    <div class="grid-x">
    {% for team in teams %}
        {% if team.game == tournament.game %}
         <div class="wf-card event-team">
             <div> {{team.title}} </div>
             <div class="event-team-players">  
             {% for member in team.members.all %}
                  {{ member.username }}
             {% endfor %}               
             </div>
         </div>
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}      
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested out the first one but it gives me only the users that created the team. So only one user appears for each team. I tested out the same code but this time I've changed players = tournament.participants.select_related('user') to players = Profile.objects.all() in views and it worked as intended but again with super slow loading time. The second one gives me an empty players, they don't appear at all.

Comment: I tried this one also players = Profile.objects.all().prefetch_related('user__teams') and in the template {% for player in players %}
                                            {% if team.id == player.active_team_id %} {{ player.user.username }} {% endif %} 
                                            {% endfor %} and it worked the load time this time is better but still takes 4 secs to load. Is it possible to reduce it ?

Comment: Is profile the same as user? If not you'll need to get user separately from user__teams, likely by select_related,  eg, Profile.objects.all().select_related('user').prefetch_related('user__teams')

Comment: It gives the same load speed and also I have noticed that removing {% for player in players %} after {% for team in teams %} caused another error. So I had to put it back

Comment: I may have been overthinking it without knowing enough about your models. I have adopted another approach in my answer - getting the team members by the teams query.